# Approximation with divided differences

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

In a proof about the approximation of Sobolev functions, on step is approximating the monomials of a polynomial with divided difference. Here are the details:

Let $\varrho \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varrho$ is not a polynomial.
With the chain rule we get for $w, x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbf{k} \in \mathbb{N}^d$
\begin{equation*}
 \varrho_\mathbf{k}(w; x):=\frac{\partial^{\vert \mathbf{k} \rvert} }{\partial w_1^{k_1} \cdots \partial w_d^{k_d}} \varrho(w \cdot x + b)=x^\mathbf{k} \varrho^{(\lvert\mathbf{k} \rvert)}(w\cdot x + b).
\end{equation*}
Because $\varrho$ is not a polynomial and therefore there exist such $b$ that $\varrho^{(\lvert \mathbf{k} \rvert)} \neq 0$
we get
\begin{equation}
 x^\mathbf{k}= \bigl( \varrho^{(\lvert \mathbf{k} \rvert)}( b)\bigr)^{-1}\varrho_\mathbf{k}(0; x). \label{eq:21}
\end{equation}
Next we define for $h > 0$ the network
\begin{equation}
 \varrho_{\mathbf{k}, h}(x) := h^{-\lvert \mathbf{k} \rvert } \sum_{0 \leq \mathbf{p} \leq \mathbf{k}} (-1)^{\lvert \mathbf{p} \rvert} \binom{\mathbf{k}}{\mathbf{p}} \varrho \bigl(h(2\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k}) \cdot x + b\bigr), \label{eq:23}
\end{equation} with $\binom{\mathbf{k}}{\mathbf{p}}:= \sum_{i=1}^{d}\binom{k_i}{p_i}$
This is apperently a divided difference approximation for $\varrho_{\mathbf{k}}(0;x)$ and we get
\begin{equation}
 \lVert \varrho_{\mathbf{k}, h} - \varrho_{\mathbf{k}}(0;\cdot) \rVert_{L^\infty} \leq M_{m, d; \varrho} h^2 \ \ \ \ \text{ for } \lvert h \rvert \leq \frac{\delta}{3md}. \label{eq:20}
\end{equation}
Does someone maybe have a clue why this works or how I can see that $\varrho_{\mathbf{k}, h}$ is a divided difference approximation?

Comment: For $d=1$ it is obvious, for higher $d$ just separate out the components.

Comment: I am sorry its not that obvious for me. Do you maybe have some hints or even some good literature that can help me?

Comment: @user10354138 I am sorry it's not that obvious for me. Do you maybe have some hints or even some good literature that can help me?

Comment: Have you tried writing out what it is when $d=1$?  $\varrho_{k,h}$ is just the usual formula for the (central) $k$-th order divided difference.